# DynamoDb list of magic entries

Tags: rust, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am using the rust API for dynamoDb and when building a [TransactWriteItem](https://docs.rs/aws-sdk-dynamodb/latest/aws_sdk_dynamodb/client/fluent_builders/struct.TransactWriteItems.html) we need to provide the name of the keys used. In previous work I used the keys `item_key` and `item_value` and `item_partition`. What is remarkable is the name of those keys do not show up in any documentation I know, and in particular not in the above link. Where could those be found?

What I am interested in is in how to put the table name. I tried `item_table_name` and other variants without success. What would be the way to put the table name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen those values used in DynamoDB. You must have been using some other flavor of database.

Here is an example we created in Rust. More can be seen [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-dynamodb-examples/tree/master/DynamoDB-SDK-Examples/rust)

```
use dynamodb::model::{AttributeValue, Put, ReturnConsumedCapacity, TransactWriteItem};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), dynamodb::Error> {
    let client = dynamodb::Client::from_env();

    let table_name = String::from("Music");

    // put 2 items in a single transact write request
    let artist1 = AttributeValue::S(String::from("No One You Know"));
    let song1 = AttributeValue::S(String::from("Call Me Today"));
    let album1 = AttributeValue::S(String::from("Somewhat Famous"));
    let awards1 = AttributeValue::N(String::from("0"));
    let released1 = AttributeValue::Bool(false);
    let put1 = Put::builder()
        .table_name(&table_name)
        .item(String::from("Artist"), artist1)
        .item(String::from("SongTitle"), song1)
        .item("AlbumTitle", album1)
        .item("Awards", awards1)
        .item("Released", released1)
        .build();
    let tx_write_1 = TransactWriteItem::builder().put(put1).build();

    let artist2 = AttributeValue::S(String::from("Acme Band"));
    let song2 = AttributeValue::S(String::from("Happy Day"));
    let album2 = AttributeValue::S(String::from("Songs About Life"));
    let awards2 = AttributeValue::N(String::from("10"));
    let released2 = AttributeValue::Bool(true);
    let put2 = Put::builder()
        .table_name(&table_name)
        .item(String::from("Artist"), artist2)
        .item(String::from("SongTitle"), song2)
        .item("AlbumTitle", album2)
        .item("Awards", awards2)
        .item("Released", released2)
        .build();
    let tx_write_2 = TransactWriteItem::builder().put(put2).build();

    let request = client
        .transact_write_items()
        .transact_items(tx_write_1)
        .transact_items(tx_write_2)
        .return_consumed_capacity(ReturnConsumedCapacity::Total);
    let resp = request.send().await?;

    println!("Tx write items: {:?}", resp);
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was confused, the "item_key" was something internal to my code.